# How can I re-download the pem file in AWS EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I made a key pair pem file called "test.pem", and I downloaded to my PC.

I made a new instance with this pem file.

Now I am in a different pc, and I don't have this pem file in my local, and my previous pc is in the middle of the sea (shipping).

How can I re-download the "test.pem" file again?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

No, you cannot download .pem file again. You can download the .pem file **ONLY** once and that is when you create a new key-pair.

Comment: So what is alternative way of that? Create new Keypair & assign to that instance?

Comment: Follow this link. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html#replacing-lost-key-pair

Answer (score 11):

You **can not** download such security key files **more than once**.

You can reuse them for multiple instances.

The best thing you can do is:

1. Download it
2. store it at `S3` (Of course in a **private access** bucket.)

Answer (score 7):

1. You cannot re download the pem file or psk file again.

SOLUTION

1. Go to network and security --> key-pair
2. Create new Key pair , SAVE IT NOW
3. Delete the original one
4. You are good to go

Comment: just to add to this, on step 2, you will see that .pem file (or whatever format you requested) will be automatically downloaded so make sure you store it securely

Answer (score 6):

You can recover you machine even if you lost pem file, there is a way:

1.create new instance with same region and VPC.

2.stop old machine (do not terminate).

3.Goto EBS , detach the root volume of old machine.

4.Now time to attach new volume to new instance(/dev/sdf).but this newly 
  attached volume will 
  be secondary for new instance because it will have its default root 
  volume.

5.Login to new machine and follow below steps:
  # mount /dev/xvdf1 /mnt
  # cp /root/.ssh/authorized_keys /mnt/root/.ssh/
  # umount /mnt

6. detach secondary volume from new instance.
7. Attach this volume back to old instance.
8. login back to old machine using pem file you got at time of creation of 
   new instance for recovery.

Comment: This is a good work around but your answer would be better if you made it clear that this is just creating a new key-pair and deploying it on the volume where the key was lost.

Answer (score 0):

My notes from doing this recently.

There's a few traps for the unwary and tools which might be unfamiliar to some.

Step 1) Detach your root volume from your machine using AWS console.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-detaching-volume.html

Amazon EC2 console  > dashboard > instances > select instance > copy instance id   i-06d2680a4d94c4f59 (29-5-22_flask_gunicorn_nginx)

instance must be in stopped state. (check dashboard as takes a few seconds after telling to stop)

Amazon EC2 console  > dashboard > volumes > select volume with matching instance ID. vol-02e720595d57d3591
'actions' dropdown > detach

Step 2) Launch a fresh EC2 instance(Not from your old machine AMI)
(same region and Virtual private cloud)
take note of the new instance id :  i-blah

Step 3) Attach your old volume to new EC2 machine
amazon EC2 console > EC2 > Volumes > selected volume.
refresh page after disconnecting the volume to update the 'actions' drop down > 'attach volume'
select the new EC2 instance
wait & refresh page until "Attached Instances" shows "attached"

Volume ID vol-blah
Attached Instances i-blah : /dev/sdf  (attached)

Step 4) Now login to new ec2 machine and mount the old EBS volume
list the available disks

lsblk
#------------------------
NAME     MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0      7:0    0 26.6M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/5163
loop1      7:1    0 55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2344
loop2      7:2    0 61.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1405
loop3      7:3    0 79.9M  1 loop /snap/lxd/22923
loop4      7:4    0 43.6M  1 loop /snap/snapd/15177
xvda     202:0    0    8G  0 disk
├─xvda1  202:1    0  7.9G  0 part /
├─xvda14 202:14   0    4M  0 part
└─xvda15 202:15   0  106M  0 part /boot/efi
xvdf     202:80   0    8G  0 disk
├─xvdf1  202:81   0  7.9G  0 part
├─xvdf14 202:94   0    4M  0 part
└─xvdf15 202:95   0  106M  0 part
#------------------------
sudo file -s /dev/xvda
/dev/xvda: DOS/MBR boot sector, extended partition table (last)
sudo file -s /dev/xvdf
/dev/xvdf: DOS/MBR boot sector, extended partition table (last)

#check file type used on existing volume
mount | grep "^/dev"
/dev/xvda1 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,discard,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/xvda15 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)

sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/xvdf

sudo mkdir /newvolume
sudo mount /dev/xvdf /newvolume/

#check file type used on existing volume
mount | grep "^/dev"
/dev/xvda1 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,discard,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/xvda15 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/xvdf on /newvolume type ext4 (rw,relatime)

$ lsblk
NAME     MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0      7:0    0 26.6M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/5163
loop1      7:1    0 55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2344
loop2      7:2    0 61.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1405
loop3      7:3    0 79.9M  1 loop /snap/lxd/22923
loop4      7:4    0 43.6M  1 loop /snap/snapd/15177
xvda     202:0    0    8G  0 disk
├─xvda1  202:1    0  7.9G  0 part /
├─xvda14 202:14   0    4M  0 part
└─xvda15 202:15   0  106M  0 part /boot/efi
xvdf     202:80   0    8G  0 disk /newvolume

#check the disk space to validate the volume mount.
cd /newvolume
df -h .

Step 5) Now go to that partition then visit home directory inside that machine and go to .ssh folder.
cd ~/.ssh
cat authorized_keys

Step 6) Now generate a new private and public key. Then paste public key into authorized_keys file.
nb: since login was setup during this ec2 instance creation, this step already complete.

Step 7) Once you done with above steps, detach that volume from this ec2 machine.
stop the new instance, wait for instance to stop.
detach new volume, wait for volume to detach.

Step 8) Now attach this volume to your old machine as root volume
attach new volume to old instance  as /dev/sda1  (see prompt as this attaches as root), wait for volume to attach.
start new instance, wait for start to complete.

nb: this error will occur if new volume not attached as root.
Failed to start the instance i-06dblah
Invalid value 'i-06dblah' for instanceId. Instance does not have a volume attached at root (/dev/sda1)

Step 9) Now try to login to your old machine with the newly generated key.

cd ~
sudo ssh-keygen -f "/root/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
sudo ssh  -i my_key_filename.pem ubuntu@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

can then remount your original volume and copy across files to retrieve.

it's worth noting here : all ssh access should be locked down to specific IP's and should be using key rotation tools. It's likely ppl will find this SE post due to their security being breached.

Answer (score -21):

Login to old instance via ftp/sftp and download the key to your pc.